# Filling variables after fetching api

Tags: javascript, api

i want to call a API and after calling it, i want to fill my cache with its data. But i dont know why its not reading my id to fill the variables

```
var Acache = {}, Bcache = {} ;

let path = window.location.pathname;
let d = new Date();
d.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
let startdatum = (Math.floor(d.getTime() / 1000.0));

let dl = new Date();
dl.setHours(24, 0, 0, -1);
let enddatum = (Math.floor(dl.getTime() / 1000.0));



fetch(APIcall).then(
    res => {
        handlecache(res, Acache);
    }
);
fetch(APIcall).then(
    res => {
        handlecache(res, Bcache);
    }
);


function handlecache(res, id) {

    res.json()
      .then((myJson) => {
          id = myJson;
            console.log(myJson);
      })

}
```

Answer (score 0):

perhaps a promise + fetch solution Ive personally used can help you here

```
let cache;

window.onload = function () {
    fetch(YOUR_API)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log('Error: ' + error.message);
    })
    .then((myJsonResponse) => {
        cache = myJsonResponse;
    });
};
```